# How to work with a development vendor package managed by dep?

Tags: git, go, govendor

How can I use a development copy/clone of a package while using `dep` and a vendor directory? The vendor directory is included in the main repository.

For example, I have forked package and replaced it with my own on github. I want to be able to edit the code and not have to `git push` + `dep ensure` for each change of the package.

If I clone the package in the vendor directory, it I won't be able to commit that directory into the main repo because it's treated as a separate repository.

I tried a trick to `.gitignore` the `.git` directory from outside the package. This works well until `dep ensure` is run, where the `.git` directory is nuked.

Comment: By removing the git tag, do you mean your question has nothing to do with git?

Comment: OK. Git-related then. Did you test my idea of relocating the .git folder elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`dep` docs](https://github.com/golang/dep#testing-changes-to-a-dependency), there is no inbuilt way of doing this as it stands.

They also recommend not modifying packages in the `vendor` directory directly, for the reasons I discovered: it gets nuked when running `dep ensure`.

Their main suggestion is to manually remove the package from the `vendor/` directory, modify it in the regular `$GOPATH`, and running `dep ensure -update <pkg>` when finished development of it.

This is sufficiently better than pushing for each change, but still requires to manually `push`/`dep ensure` when completing the development work.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to "ignoring `.git`" is to keep the `.git` folder elsewhere! (well outside of your Go project)

Any time you need to execute a git command in the vendored sub-project, you would need to use an alias to the git command, which would be:

```
alias gg='git --git-dir=/path/to/elsewhere/.git --work-tree=/path/to/vendored/subproject'
# Windows
doskey gg=git --git-dir=C:\path\to\elsewhere\.git --work-tree=C:\path\to\vendored\subproject $*
```

That way, you can still benefit from version-controled operations within your vendored subproject.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is a novel approach, but slightly hacky in my opinion. I will continue working out a cleaner approach.

Comment: @GeraldKaszuba I would argue it is not "hacky", and promote a clean separation of Golang dependency management on one side, and source control management on the other.